# match any part of string "tomorrow" starting at tom

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a javascript datepicker and I am changing dates as they type in Monday, tuesday etc.

I am looking for a concise way to match on any part of the string tomorrow but not until at least "tom" has been entered.

I want to highlight the next date when the user types:
"tom"
"tommo"
"tommor"
"tommoro"
"tommorow"

Without being overly explicit, how can I match on any of these strings?

Comment: Fyi, `tommorow` is spelled `tomorrow`

Comment: You'll highlight the next date as soon as the user has types "tom", right ? Then do you really need to match further parts of the word ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
\btom(?:o(?:r(?:r(?:ow?)?)?)?)?\b
```

`(?:)`  is a [non capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) it is more efficient than a capture group. It has the same meaning as a capture group. It's used when you want to group elements but there're no needs to capture anything.

Comment: does not match after tomorr, tomorro or tomorrow

Comment: @dagda1: Right, I missed an `r`. Corrected.

Comment: great stuff, if possible could you give a brief explanation.  I get the word boundary but that is about it :).

Answer (score 1):

If you want one regex to match:

```
tom, tomo, tomor, tomorr, tomorro, tomorrow
```

Use:

```
^tom(o(r(r(ow?)?)?)?)?$
```

Comment: that regex only matches on tom

Comment: @dagda1 Your question requested to match on `tom` as well...?

Comment: @dagda1 This regex tests if string matches tested string. It works for every combination I've described.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to match other parts of tomorrow when it should already match on the part "tom"? Just match for `tom`

Answer (score 0):

This regexp will match what you want :

```
tom(o(r(r(ow?)?)?)?)?
```

But as I said in my comment, matching "tom" may be enough.